# Library for using plates in bayesian networks(preferably c++)

Tags: c++, bayesian, bayesian-networks

In my Bayesian network there are plenty of repetitive variables leading to the use of plates(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plate_notation). I do not want the exponential space complexity in implementing the bayesian network. But the way traditional libraries(like dlib on c++) offers bayesian network, it is always exponential. Is it possible to actually use the plates and reduce the space complexity? If yes, please help with some libraries that does this(Preferably c++)